# WinRT - Starting/Registering IBackgroundTask in universal application

Tags: javascript, c#, windows, windows-runtime

I would like to start my IBackgroundTask when my application starts up.

I have added my task to the .appxmanifest.xml file, and my extensions tag now looks like this

```
<Extensions>
  <Extension Category="windows.backgroundTasks" EntryPoint="CordovaApp.Library.UploadTask">
    <BackgroundTasks>
      <Task Type="systemEvent" />
      <Task Type="timer" />
    </BackgroundTasks>
  </Extension>
</Extensions>
```

My IBackgroundTask class is called UploadTask and is held in another project which has the outtype set to Windows Runtime Component.

Here is a cut down version of the code, so you can see the namespace etc

```
namespace CordovaApp.Library
{
    public sealed class UploadTask : IBackgroundTask
    {
        public async void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
        {
            var connectionProfile = NetworkInformation.GetInternetConnectionProfile();

            // connectionProfile can be null (e.g. airplane mode)
            if (connectionProfile != null && connectionProfile.IsWlanConnectionProfile)
            {
                // custom code here
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have added a reference to this project to my universal runtime component project.

Everything builds fine.

Now to start the application, i guess i have to use WinJs, so i have the following code.

```
var uploadTaskName = 'UploadTask';
var tasks = Windows.ApplicationModel.Background.BackgroundTaskRegistration.allTasks;
var uploadTaskFound = false;

for (var i = 0; i < tasks.length; i++) {
    if (tasks[i].Value.name == uploadTaskName) {
        successCallback();
        return;
    }
}

Windows.ApplicationModel.Background.BackgroundExecutionManager.requestAccessAsync().then(function() {
    var builder = new Windows.ApplicationModel.Background.BackgroundTaskBuilder();

    builder.name = "Upload Task";
    builder.taskEntryPoint = "CordovaApp.Library.UploadTask";
    builder.setTrigger(new Windows.ApplicationModel.Background.TimeTrigger(15, false));
    return builder.register();
}).done(function () {
    successCallback();
}, function(err) {
    errorCallback(err);
});
```

Now the requestAccessAsync method always throws an exception of

> 0x80004005 - JavaScript runtime error: Unspecified error
>   WinRT information: The application is not lock-screen capable.

Have a registered everything correctly? I am running this via Visual Studio 2013 on a laptop.

Comment: Check if http://stackoverflow.com/a/14258877/3956290 helps

Answer (score 1):

Seems that because the app was already installed, the permission was not given.

By uninstalling the application, and re-running it, i was then prompted to allow/disallow the background service to run.  Checked allow, and now seems to work